# Spring actuator with Prometheus, custom MetricWriter is never called

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, prometheus

I'd like to add metric measurement for my Spring boot app. Metrics would be displayed via grafana.

I have found nice [article](http://blog.monkey.codes/actuator-and-prometheus/) for integration spring actuator with prometheus.

According to the sample, I should implement my custom `MetricWriter`  for updating corresponding `Counter` or `Gauge` in the Prometheus `CollectorRegistry`
It looks like this:

```
class PrometheusMetricWriter implements MetricWriter {

    CollectorRegistry registry

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Gauge> counters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Gauge> gauges = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()

    @Autowired
    PrometheusMetricWriter(CollectorRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry
    }

    @Override
    void increment(Delta<?> delta) {
        counter(delta.name).inc(delta.value.doubleValue())
    }

    @Override
    void reset(String metricName) {
        counter(metricName).clear()
    }

    @Override
    void set(Metric<?> value) {
        println "inside metric writer"
        gauge(value.name).set(value.value.doubleValue())
    }

    private Counter counter(String name) {
        def key = sanitizeName(name)
        counters.computeIfAbsent key, { k ->
            Counter.build().name(k).help(k).register(registry)
        }
    }

    private Gauge gauge(String name) {
        def key = sanitizeName(name)
        gauges.computeIfAbsent key, { k ->
            Gauge.build().name(k).help(k).register(registry)
        }
    }

    private String sanitizeName(String name) {
        return name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "_")
    }
}
```

The other 3 required elements are: `PrometheusEndpoint`, `PrometheusMvcEndpoint`, `PrometheusEndpointContextConfiguration`.

After all, the collected metrics could be reviewed by calling 'http://localhost:8080/prometheus' url.

And the result should look like this:

```
# HELP gauge_com_egalacoral_spark_stage_vto gauge_com_egalacoral_spark_stage_vto
# TYPE gauge_com_egalacoral_spark_stage_vto gauge
gauge_com_egalacoral_spark_stage_vto 4.0
# HELP gauge_com_egalacoral_spark_test_vfl gauge_com_egalacoral_spark_test_vfl
# TYPE gauge_com_egalacoral_spark_test_vfl gauge
gauge_com_egalacoral_spark_test_vfl 16.0
```

But, I am receiving **an empty page**. 
Here is test class for collecting some metrics.

```
class Runner {

    @Autowired
    GaugeService gaugeService

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Runner.class)

    private ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of('Europe/London')

    private Integer delay = 10

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000L)
    void runOnTest() throws Exception {

        def now = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId)
        println "collect metrics"
        gaugeService.submit("test", 2.0)

    }
}
```

**P.S:** I have noticed that `GaugeService` has several implementation, and in my App this is `DropwizardMetricServices`. This implementation already contains it's own metric registry, which collects my metrics. 
So, when I am calling  '/prometheus' endpoint, I am getting an empty page, as the `CollectorRegistry' in my custom`PrometheusMetricWriter` is never populated with my metrics.

So please, tell me how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the reason why `DropwizardMetricServices` implementation of `GaugeService` is using.

According to the spring docs:

> **50.10 Dropwizard Metrics**
>
> A default MetricRegistry Spring bean will be created when you declare a dependency to the
>   **io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core** library; you can also register you
>   own @Bean instance if you need customizations. Users of the Dropwizard
>   ‘Metrics’ library will find that Spring Boot metrics are automatically
>   published to com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry. Metrics from the
>   MetricRegistry are also automatically exposed via the /metrics
>   endpoint
>
> When Dropwizard metrics are in use, the default CounterService and
>   GaugeService are replaced with a DropwizardMetricServices, which is a
>   wrapper around the MetricRegistry (so you can @Autowired one of those
>   services and use it as normal). You can also create “special”
>   Dropwizard metrics by prefixing your metric names with the appropriate
>   type (i.e. timer.*, histogram.* for gauges, and meter.* for counters).

Somehow **io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core** library was included to the project dependencies.
After, I removing it, all start to work as expected.